# How to filter Crystal Report to show pages 1 to 5 only

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a report that have more than 1000 pages,now i want to display reports from page 1 to 5,page 6 to 10,and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Crystal Reports should have a `PageNumber` variable you can reference.  Using that, you can conditionally suppress each section of your report by the desired page number range, such as:

```
PageNumber >= 1 and PageNunber <= 5
```